# Kotlin/Spring - Fowarding post request from one service to another

Tags: spring-boot, http, kotlin

We had a spring web-app that used to handle all front and back end logic. As we need to scale we have split that into two microservices. How would I go about 'forwarding' a post request to another url (including its body and authentication headers). For example:

`microservice1` has an endpoint `/api/doSomething`

`microservice2` has an endpoint `/privateUrl/doSomething`

I want the user to hit the endpoint on `microservice1` which will post to `microservice2`  and return the result.

I have tried with RestTemplate without much luck, i keep getting error "Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class..." from microservice1, i suspect this is because microservice1 doesnt know how to parse the body object microservice2  requires.

microservice1:

```
@PostMapping("/api/DoSomething")
fun postIT(request: HttpServletRequest, @PathVariable one: String, @PathVariable two: String){ ...}
```

microservice2:

```
@CrossOrigin
@PostMapping("/privateUrl/doSomething")
fun postIT(request: HttpServletRequest, @RequestParam one: String, @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "true") two: String,@RequestBody it: IT) { ... }
```

I know i can parse the entire request in `microservice1` and then send it to `microservice2`, however is there a way to just 'forward' the http request to a new url?

Comment: Would a redirect work? You could return a [RedirectView](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html) from your `@PostMapping`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean , but if you want to communicate from one server to another you can always use rest template (or any other) and send http request from one service to another, you can see examples here
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_rest_template.htm
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

take a look it should work for you.